# How to rewrite the table qualifier at runtime with JOOQ

Tags: jooq

When generating code using JOOQ for a SQL Server database the generation creates three-part qualifiers like: `[catalog].[schema].[table]`. This is exactly what I want when working with the SQL Server databases but is an issue when using the generated code with another database like an H2 in memory database for unit testing.

The H2 dialect does not support these three-part qualifiers, H2 expects something like [catalog].[table]. This causes syntax errors when executing commands like the following against H2:

```
context.createTable(TBLBUSINESSENTITY).columns(TBLBUSINESSENTITY.fields()).execute();
```

To solve this I need to change the qualifier at runtime which I thought could be done using a render mapping and mapped schema. Unfortunately, this seems to only have the ability to modify the schema portion of the qualifier like this:

```
Settings settings = new Settings().withRenderMapping(new RenderMapping().withSchemata(
      new MappedSchema().withInput("dbo").withOutput("mySchema")));
```

Given the qualifier `[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]`, this maps to `[MyDatabase].[mySchema].[MyTable]` but I cant figure out how to remove that section entirely.

Is there some way to rewrite the mapping to `[MyDatabase].[MyTable]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this setting instead:

```java
Settings settings = new Settings()
  .withRenderCatalog(false)
  .withRenderMapping(new RenderMapping()
    .withCatalogs(new MappedCatalog()
      .withInput("MyDatabase")
      .withSchemata(new MappedSchema()
        .withInput("dbo")
        .withOutput("MyDatabase"))));
```